# XSLT collection() function regex not recognizing '?'

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm trying to grab 3.XML through 6.XML from the list below:

3.XML

4.XML

4_1.XML

5.XML

5_1.XML

6.XML

31.XML

`collection('file:///.../?select=[3-6](_[0-9]+)?.XML` only grabs 4_1.XML and 5_1.XML and therefore doesn't recognize the '?'. Any suggestions on how to fix this? I'm using Saxon-PE 9.5.1.3.

Comment: What happens when you escape the question mark `?` as `%3F`? Does that help?

Comment: I tried escaping it but it didn't help. I also tried collection(iri-to-uri('file...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the dialect of regex used by saxon but it might be they use a different style of Reluctant quantifiers. You may need something like this:
"X??" matches X, once or not at all. "X*?" matches X, zero or more times

Comment: X?? and X*? didn't work either.

Comment: Consider to edit your question with exact information about the Saxon version you are using. I have added the `saxon` tag so hopefully you will get an answer from Saxonica.

Comment: For anyone interested, I ended up bypassing the question mark and used xsl:for-each to select two separate collections. I then used xsl:sort to achieve the desired output.

Comment: I would expect it to work if special characters such as "?" (and perhaps "[" etc) are %HH-escaped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, @Florent, your diagnosis is correct.

Though the documentation fails to mention that in this glob-like pattern, not only is * treated as meaning .* (any sequence of characters), but ? is treated as meaning .? (any single character, or none).

I found a workaround, which is to replace the "?" in the regex by `%7B0,1%7D` - that is, `{0,1}` %-escaped to make it valid in a URI.

Comment: I tested the workaround you suggested and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the parameter `select` in a collection URI is not a regex, it is a glob-like pattern (like you would use in a shell).  See the [documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!sourcedocs/collections) for details.

In your case, I think the best you can do is `?select=*.XML` I am afraid.